# inline javascript callback onclick using mustache templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mustache

[Screenshot of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0IOW.png)

I'm having an issue invoking the inline javascript inside the mustache template file (.hjs).

when I click "Verify", the script tag and console logs do not run. It is not pulling the input code I type into the input box either.

For context: I am sending the mustache template (html) from my node server to an iFrame on the front end (React). I want the template to interact with the user and send an API call to my server and verify the 2FA.

I am sending variables to the javascript through {{ var }}, which is standard for mustache.

My thoughts: this code works in a regular **index.html** file.

any help or tips appreciated! I can try any suggestions locally to debug further.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <body>
    <div id="inline-widget" style="margin:0 auto;width: 360px;padding:5px">
      <p style="font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Segoe UI','Roboto','Oxygen','Ubuntu','Cantarell','Fira Sans','Droid Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;color:#48545d;font-size:14px;line-height:125%;margin:10px auto 20px;text-align:center">
        Please complete your purchase by entering the 4 character code at the end of your recent charge description.
      </p>
      <img style="width: 350px;text-align:center;border:1px solid black" src="https://d2xxy1rwbjzckp.cloudfront.net/verification.jpeg" alt="Example"></img>
      <p style="font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Segoe UI','Roboto','Oxygen','Ubuntu','Cantarell','Fira Sans','Droid Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;color:#48545d;font-size:11px;line-height:125%;margin-bottom:10px auto 20px;text-align:left">
        Code = 3122 in this example
      </p>
      <p id="error-message" style="font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Segoe UI','Roboto','Oxygen','Ubuntu','Cantarell','Fira Sans','Droid Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;color:#48545d;font-size:11px;line-height:125%;margin-bottom:10px auto 20px;text-align:center;color:red"></p>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="2faCode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="4 digit code" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"/>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="verifyButton" type="button">Verify</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const button = document.getElementById('verifyButton'); 

      button.addEventListener('click', async _ => {
      try {     
        const verifyCode = document.getElementById('2faCode').value;
        console.log('start!: ', verifyCode);
        const response = await fetch({{ callbackUrl }}, {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderId: {{ orderId }},
            verificationCode: {{ verifyCode }}
          })
        });

        const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");

        if (contentType === 'text/html; charset=utf-8') {
          const textResponse = await response.text();
          document.getElementById("inline-widget").innerHTML = textResponse;
        } else {
          const parsedResponse = await response.json();
          document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML = parsedResponse.message;
        }
      } catch(err) {
        document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML = err;
        console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
      }
      });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```